# Get last folder and file name from full filename in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, plsql

I have following working code to extract file name along with lowest folder name, in SQL Server 2012. There can be any level of sub folders – I need only the innermost folder and the file name. Is there a more easy to read approach in SQL Server for this?

Expected Result

```
MySubFolder/MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip
```

**Current Working SQL**

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(200) =  'D:\SourceFiles\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip'
DECLARE @TotalRecords INT
DECLARE @SectionName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @FileOnly VARCHAR(128)

SET @FileName = REPLACE( @FileName, '/', '\')
DECLARE @xml xml = '<r><n>' + REPLACE( @FileName, '\', '</n><n>') + '</n></r>'

DECLARE @FoldersList TABLE(FId INT IDENTITY(1,1), FolderOrFileName VARCHAR(128))
INSERT INTO @FoldersList (FolderOrFileName)
SELECT n.value( '.', 'varchar(200)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('r/n') n(n)


SELECT @TotalRecords = COUNT(*) FROM @FoldersList
SELECT @SectionName = FolderOrFileName FROM @FoldersList WHERE Fid = (@TotalRecords - 1)
SELECT @FileOnly = FolderOrFileName FROM @FoldersList WHERE Fid = (@TotalRecords)

SELECT @SectionName+'/'+@FileOnly
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xp_diretree and see the depth and if it's a file or folder...

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(200) =  'D:\SourceFiles\MyFolder\MySubFolder\

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FileNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ProductivityFileNames
CREATE TABLE #FileNames (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
    ,depth int
    ,isfile bit)
INSERT #FileNames (subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC xp_dirtree @FileName 

SELECT * 
FROM 
   #FileNames
WHERE 
      (depth = (select max(depth) - 1 from #FileNames) and isFile = 0) --limit to the last sub-folder
   or (depth = (select max(depth) from #FileNames) and isFile = 1)     --this would be the files in the deepest folder
```

**If this is simply a string that needs parsing...**

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(200) =  'D:\SourceFiles\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip'

select right(@FileName,CHARINDEX('\',reverse(@FileName),CHARINDEX('\',reverse(@FileName)) + 1) - 1)
```

Comment: They are trying to parse a string. There is no indication the folder is even on the server.

Comment: Added a version for string. I didn't think this was the case since, this has been asked a ton of times on SO as you are aware @MartinSmith. Thanks for pointing it out to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(200) = 
  'D:\SourceFiles\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip'

SELECT RIGHT(@FileName, CHARINDEX('\', FileNameRev, 1+ CHARINDEX('\', FileNameRev)) - 1) 
FROM (SELECT REVERSE('\' + @FileName)) V(FileNameRev)
```

Comment: Syntax highlighter definitely seems broken recently.

Answer (score 1):

Another option.

If the path is in a table, easy to convert into a CROSS APPLY.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(200) =  'D:\SourceFiles\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip'

Select reverse(concat(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)'),'\',xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
 From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(reverse(@FileName),'\','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A
```

**Returns**

```
MySubFolder\MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip
```

If Table

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, FileName varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'D:\SourceFiles\MyFolder\MySubFolder\MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip')
,(2,'D:\MyFile_4.0.zip')


Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select ShortPath = reverse(concat(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)'),'\',xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                 From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(reverse(A.FileName),'\','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ShortPath
1   MySubFolder\MyFile_4.0_20170901031307_2697.zip
2   D:\MyFile_4.0.zip
```