# Fetch element at particular position

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the SQL syntax to find last directory name from a file path.
For example I want to fetch the name of the last Directory i.e. `C`

Input:

```
/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2
```

Output:

```
C
```

Comment: what DBMS is this - SQL Server? MySQL?
How do you identify a directory? based on prefix?

Comment: it would be reasonable to do this as a post-processing computation, not on the database side

Comment: DBMS- SQL Server and Prefix would be "Directory" for a directory and I want to get name of last directory in the  given path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have very good string processing capabilities.  But, with some effort, you can do what you want.

The key idea is that the last "Directory_" is the first "_yrotceriD" in the reversed string.  Then some lopping and adjusting gets what you want:

```
select v.*, left(v.dir, charindex('/', v.dir) - 1) as dirname
from (values ('/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2') ) t(path) cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.path, 1, len(t.path) - charindex(reverse('Directory_'), reverse(t.path)) + 1, ''))) v(dir)
```

Comment: it worked for me . But what if ''/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2'' is data of a column of a table . It is giving me the error.

Comment: Lets say ,  DirectoryName  is Coulmn of  locations table :  select v.*, left(v.dir, charindex('/', v.dir) - 1) as dirname
from (values (DirectoryName) ) t(path) cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.path, 1, len(t.path) - charindex(reverse('Directory_'), reverse(t.path)) + 1, ''))) v(dir) from locations

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(100)='/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2'

SELECT SUBSTRING( @path,LEN(@path)-LEN(SUBSTRING(@path,PATINDEX('%folder%',@path), 100))-1, 1)
```

Comment: This is not necessary 1 character . There can be anything '/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_CBCCCV/Folder1/Folder2'. We need to fetch the whole string that is after last Directory_

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `select right`or `left`? If it is a string I think it is doable. Also there is something in there you will have to play around.

Comment: if this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226235/get-last-folder-and-file-name-from-full-filename-in-sql-server

Comment: There is no fixed position of last directory so i cant use RIGHT or LEFT to fetch character.  There can be any level of sub folders

Comment: Not really an answer... more suited to a comment.